# c# read a text file. How to avoid reading it again

Tags: c#, readline

I'm new to programming and I have a problem with calling a method.
I read a text file in the first method and saved each line in a list. And the return type of the method was List so that I could bring any specific line of the text file in other method. But the problem is that I have to read the text file over and over whenever I call the first method. I have to call the method more than 100 times and the length of the text file is over 1000 lines.

```
public static List<double> readLine(int line) 
{
    //read a text file and save in readList
    return readList[line];
}

public static double useList()
{
    readLine(1);
    readLine(2);
    readLine(3);
    readLine(4);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read the entire file and save all the lines in a `List<string>` then only use that for each line.

Comment: We don't like pictures of code here.  Always post it as text.  Not to be too critical here, but you have managed to post an amazing amount of problematic code in a short amount of lines.  Start with a tutorial.

Comment: @Jimenemex But even though I read the entire file, whenever I call the first method, I have to read the text file again. Right?

Comment: In the future, please refrain from posting **images** of code.  Post code as *text*

Comment: I think you need to fix your process before addressing your code.  Why must `readLine` read the file each time?  `readLine` isn't given a filename, so I assume it's some static file which you could just read and store once.  What is the consumer `useList` going to be doing with the results of `readLine`?  What is your logic here actually trying to do?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie What I'm going to do is the basic arithmetic calculations with numbers in the text file. That is why I needed a specific line of the text file. But my problem is that if I call readLine, then the method reads the entire text file again

Comment: What should be the outcome if a line can't parse to a double?  Arbitrary value?  Throw an exception?  The answer by Jimenemex should get you close to what you're after, with something like `public static double readLine(int line) => double.Parse(lines[line]);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, just read the entire file once and save it into a `List<string>` using [File.ReadAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2) (Cast the output to a list). Once you have that, then you can just use the `List<string>` directly without having to go back to read the file each time. See below.

```
public class Program
{
    private static List<string> lines;
    public static void Main()
    {
        // At this point lines will have the entire file. Each line in a different index in the list
        lines = File.ReadAllLines("..path to file").ToList();

        useList(); // Use it however
    }

    // Just use the List which has the same data as the file
    public static string readFromList(int num)
    {
        return lines[num];
    } 

    public static void useList()
    {
        string line1 = readFromList(1); // Could even be string line1 = lines[SomeNum];
        string line2 = readFromList(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anthony If this answer resolved your question (or got you to a resolution), remember to click the checkmark to accept this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to read text from a text file all in one shot?

If so try
 figure out where this file is located

```
string path = @"C:\path to textfile.txt";
```

then use system.io to read the files and save them.. this will return an array of strings

```
string[] textfromfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

depending on what you want to do with the text file information you can begin to process it from here..

let me know if this solution helps.